# SSISDB ldf file location

Tags: ssis

Our SQL Server instance has the following settings:

Database default locations:

- Data: D:\
- Log: E:\

When creating a new database with defaults (`create database test`) it respects these settings.

When we create a new SSISDB catalog, using these steps https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.110).aspx (through SSMS or PowerShell) it appears to ignore the log file setting, and put both the data file and log file in D:.

Is there a way to create this catalog with the settings being respected, or do we need to make sure to re-arrange everything once we've already created the catalog?

Comment: Is your system DB default location is D:\?

Comment: Is there a separate default for system databases? I am only aware of one default location setting, which I described in my original post.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\Setup`  key `SQLDataRoot` where you will see system database location.  Not sure if  `D:`  is in your case. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer` key `DefaultData` and `DefaultLog` will have your default user database location.